# Unix tr command to convert lower case to upper AND upper to lower case

Tags: unix, pipeline, tr

So I was searching around and using the command `tr` you can convert from lower case to upper case and vice versa. But is there a way to do this both at once?

So:

```
$ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' or  $ tr A-Z a-z
```

Will turn *"Hello World ABC"* to *"hello world abc"*, but what I want is *"hELLO wORLD abc"*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
 tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `tr '[a-zA-Z]' '[A-Za-z]'` is more straight forward, and easier to remember.

Comment: `tr a-zA-Z A-Za-z`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\L&` and `\U&` to convert to lower and upper case respectively:

`$echo "SUJIT dhamale " | sed 's/.*/\L&/g'`

Result: `sujit dhamale`

`$ echo "SUJIT dhamale " | sed 's/.*/\U&/g'`

Result: `SUJIT DHAMALE`